# Mod rewriting www.domain.com/branch to www.website.com/ and the opposite

Tags: apache, url, mod-rewrite

I have a particular need and I wanted to have some insights on the proper solution using .htaccess mod_rewriting.

Basically I need to map a domain to a subfolder of another domain. All requests for www.website.com should be redirected to the contents on www.domain.com/branch, while preserving www.website.com in the address bar of browsers. Also requests to www.website.com/subpage, should be redirected to www.domain.com/branch/subpage, so the www.website.com/subpage URL is preserved.

Requests for www.domain.com/branch should be rewritten as www.website.com, and requests for www.domain.com/branch/subfolder should rewrite as www.website.com/subfolder.

I'm using Expression Engine templating sistem, but this shouldn't be an issue. 
What would be the correct mod_rewriting?

Later I will have to "sniff" the url in order to serve a different logo and colors for the same content but I guess I can make it with javascript then?

So far I've been exploring the matter with such instructions:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website.com\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/(.*) /branch/$1 [L]
```

But the whole matter seems to be far more complicate… 
Can an expert point me right to obtain everything I need with mod_rewrite?

Comment: Are website.com and domain.com hosted on the same server? If so, are they in the same virualhost (do they both point to the same folder on the server)?

Comment: Yes, they're both on the same server and they both point to the same folder. As Expression engine makes use of dynamic paths such as domain.com/branch though, I can't just point requests to www.website.com to www.domain.com/branch… using vhost, it'll throw a server error

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#internally redirect request for website.com to the /branch folder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/branch
RewriteRule ^(.*) /branch/$1 [L]

# redirect direct request for /branch to the website.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^branch/(.*) http://www.website.com/$1 [R=302,L]
```

I'm assuming you are putting these rules into htaccess, otherwise you would need leading slashes in the RewriteRules

Comment: Unfortunately it throws a Server Error… but it must have something to do with my .htaccess rules which are needed in order to remove index.php from Expression Engine configuration apparently… If you don't mind having a look, the .htaccess file is here: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2899749/htaccess.txt

Comment: Where did you put the rules? You need to place them in front of the other rewriterules.

Comment: No matter where I put them… I tried it on top of the page but still get the error. Thanks.